# How to center a Pivot header in Fluent UI?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui

I want to use a pivot in Fluent UI to display the menu.

```
<Pivot linkSize={PivotLinkSize.large}>
        <PivotItem headerText='userInfo' headerButtonProps={}>
            <UserPage />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem headerText='userConfig'>
            <UserSetting />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem headerText='Store'>
            <StorePage />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem headerText='SubInfo'>
            <SubInfo />
        </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

It displays like this:

[image: pic]

But I want to let the Pivot Header to the center, I have tried to change the styles attribute, but didn't have any progress.

How to align the the Pivot Header to center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all buttons to be horizontically centered, just make the Pivot a flexbox and justify all of its items centered:

```
<Pivot linkSize={PivotLinkSize.large}
       styles={{ root: { display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' } }}>
        <PivotItem headerText='userInfo' headerButtonProps={}>
            <UserPage />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem headerText='userConfig'>
            <UserSetting />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem headerText='Store'>
            <StorePage />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem headerText='SubInfo'>
            <SubInfo />
        </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I have Text and Icon. nothing I try in the devtools puts them in the center

Comment: If you make a fiddle or a codepen, I could have a look at whats different to the example above.

Comment: It is inside a react component in a window on top of SPFx webpart. I would not know how to get just this into a fiddle.

Comment: I fear that I cannot help with this. I guess you're missing a `display: flex` or `flex: 1` on some level. Sorry that I cannot tell you more.